# Take string input until it is equal to "/0"

Tags: c, for-loop, multidimensional-array, nested-loops, c-strings

I want the user to enter a maximum of R strings either until the loop ends or until they hit ENTER so basically the input would be equal to "\0".
Then I want to count the amount of characters that have been entered by the user.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define R 5
#define C 2


int main(){

    char Pin[R][C];

    char str[100];

    for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
        
            printf("Enter a string: ");
            scanf("%s", &Pin[i]);
            if(str == "\0"){break;}
            strcpy(Pin[i],str);
    }
    int sum = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
        for(int j = 0; j < C; j++){

            int kapa = sizeof Pin[i];
            sum += kapa;
        }
    }

    printf("\n\n%d", sum);

    
    return 0;
}
```

This is my code, but whenever i hit enter to get another input it will skip once.
Another problem is that it counts the character "\n" as well and i'd prefer it if it wouldnt.

Comment: Would be equal to "\0"...

Comment: Add expected valid input and output to the question to make it more cogent.

Comment: Your only input function call is `scanf("%s")`, which will scan words of non-whitespace and therefore won't contain a newline, `'\n'`. It cannot scan empty strings. Your maximum string length `C == 2`  is very small -- it can accomodate only single-letter strings. Finally, `sizeof P[i]` is the defined size of each string, `C` in this case, regardless of its actual length.

Comment: Why do you copy the undefined contents of `str` to `Pin[i]`? You probably meant to scan into `str`, then copy, but you scan into `Pin[i]` directly. When you copy, you overwrite the scanned string. And you've probably learned that you cannot compare strings with `==` in C.

Comment: `&p[i]` will be of type `char(*)[2]`, which is wrong for `%s` format specifier, so undefined behaviour (even though the address itself would fit).  Just use `p[i]` and don't worry about that being an array itself, it decays to a pointer of correct type (`char *`) implicitly.

Comment: About checking for an empty string: Easiest and most efficient is just to check if first character is the null character, so simply `if(*str == 0)` (note the asterisk! note, too, it is `0`, *not* `'0'` – alternatively you could use `'\0'`).

Comment: `kapa` would in your case *always* give 2, as that's the length of the array in bytes.

Comment: As you are inputting strings only anyway, you really should prefer [`fgets`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fgets) for – it allows you to limit maximum input more easily (`scanf` actually allows to do so, too, but less convenient) and thus to prevent writing beyond array bounds (-> undefined behaviour!) by the user entering too long strings. Note, though, that it would include the newline of the user pressing enter, so for testing an empty string you'd have to check for `if(*p[i] == '\n')`

Comment: `"/0"` is not `"\0"` is not `'\0'`. What are you actually asking here? Though obviously `str == "\0"` is nonsense regardless of what you are attempting to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presented program does not make a sense.

For example each character array Pin[i] can contain a string with at most one character if not to count the terminating zero character `'\0'` of string.

Within this for loop

```
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
    
        printf("Enter a string: ");
        scanf("%s", &Pin[i]);
        if(str == "\0"){break;}
        strcpy(Pin[i],str);
}
```

there is used uninitialized array `str` that is not changed within the loop.

This if statement

```
if(str == "\0"){break;}
```

is always evaluates to false because there are compared two pointers of first characters of the array `str` and of the string literal `"\0"`. As they occupy different extents of memory then their addresses are different.

Also the information about how many strings were entered stored nowhere.

These nested for loops

```
for(int i = 0; i < R; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < C; j++){

        int kapa = sizeof Pin[i];
        sum += kapa;
    }
}
```

also do not make a sense. For example the index `j` is not used. The expression `sizeof Pin` is a constant expression and always evaluates to `2` by the definition of the array `Pin`. You need to use the function `strlen` instead of the operator `sizeof`.

It seems what you mean is the following

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    enum { R = 5, C = 100 };
    char Pin[R][C];

    size_t n = 0;

    for (; n < R; n++)
    {
        char s[C];
        s[0] = '\0';

        printf( "Enter a string: " );

        if ( !fgets( s, sizeof( s ), stdin ) || s[0] == '\n') break;

        s[strcspn( s, "\n" )] = '\0';

        strcpy( Pin[n], s );
    }

    size_t sum = 0;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
        sum += strlen( Pin[i] );
    }

    printf( "\nsum of lengths of the strings is %zu\n", sum );
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter a string: 1
Enter a string: 12
Enter a string: 123
Enter a string:

sum of lengths of the strings is 6
```

Comment: One question only, why do you use size_t ? I am not familiar with it yet

Comment: @DnsStratos The return type of the function strlen  and the type of the value of an expression with the sizeof operator is the unsigned integer type size_t.